# Day/Month filtered Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, subquery

I have these current results

```
 PersonName Team    Daily Amount    Date
    Alex      4          10       2017-01-11
    Alex      4          10       2017-01-11
    Alex      4          10       2017-01-11
    Ben       1          10       2017-02-11
    Ben       1          10       2017-02-11
    Ben       1          10       2017-01-11
    Fred      3          10       2017-01-11
    Fred      3          10       2017-01-11
    Fred      3          10       2017-01-11
    Sam       2          10       2017-02-11
    Sam       2          10       2017-01-11
    Sam       2          10       2017-01-11
    Tom       2          10       2017-01-11
    Tom       2          10       2017-02-11
    Tom       2          10       2017-01-11
```

Now, i am looking to create a daily and month so far figure in two separate columns.

I am looking for a result like this:

```
 PersonName Team    Daily Amount    Date        Monthly Figure
    Alex      4          30       2017-01-11      30
    Ben       1          10       2017-01-11      30
    Fred      3          10       2017-01-11      30
    Sam       2          20       2017-01-11      30
    Tom       2          20       2017-01-11      30
```

So far i have a query like this but i am not sure this is the best approach. Its giving me different grouped sum results than what i expected.

```
SELECT P.PersonName, min(P.Team) AS [Team],
SUM(F.Amount) AS [Daily Amount], min(F.Date) AS [Date], MTD.[Month To Date]
FROM Person P
JOIN Figure F on P.PersonID =F.PersonFK
WHERE DATEDIFF( d, F.Date, GETDATE() ) = 1 
GROUP BY P.PersonName


JOIN 
(SELECT 
P.PersonName, min(P.Team) AS [Team],
SUM(F.Amount) AS [Month To Date]
, min(F.Date) AS [Date]
FROM Person P
JOIN Figure F on P.PersonID =F.PersonFK
F.Date BETWEEN CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
AND  GETDATE() 
GROUP BY P.PersonName ) MTD
ON MTD.PersonName = P.PersonName
```

I have tried both a join sub query as well as using union but i cant get quite get the result i want. Can anyone advise me further? thanks

SQL FIDDLE - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23bbb/12

Comment: What happened to "2017-02-11"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i want to limit the daily to 2017-01-11 but show the whole month total. I can remove the date field - its not important. Its just there to demonstrate what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to find an amount spent by each person on a specific day and compare it with an amount spend in that month

```
declare @day date = '01-11-17'

select P.PersonName, 
    P.Team AS [Team],
   sum(case when date = @day then f.amount end) AS [daily amount] ,
   @day AS [Date],   
   sum(F.Amount) AS [monthly amount] 
from Person P
join Figure F on P.PersonID =F.PersonFK
where month(F.date) = month(@day)
group by P.PersonName, P.Team
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b318/2)

Comment: this is not right. e.g tom's monthly figure should be 30 not 40

Comment: @RyanGadsdon it is right for the data that are in my demo.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon note that in YOUR data (that you provide in your fiddle) you have all January data in one day, therefore, there would be no difference between monthly and daily data. So I have added two values and Tom has total amount 40 in January.